# Convert datetime to string/varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a view in SQL Server which uses dates to determine which tables to access data from. The problem is it only seems to work when given the date as a `varchar` like `'20120423'`.

So I am trying to dynamically create this date with `GETDATE()` instead of having to use the typed out version. When I run the top `SELECT` statement it returns `'20120423'` like I would expect but when I try to compare the two values they are not equal and the `IF` statement prints `'VALUES ARE NOT THE SAME'`.

```
SELECT 
    '''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) +'''' 

IF '''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) +''''  = '20120423' 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'VALUES ARE THE SAME'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'VALUES ARE NOT THE SAME'
END
```

I'm kind of lost as to where to go from here. Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**:
With the answers given then these two queries should be the same even though they are treated differently by my view.

```
SELECT * 
FROM DatesView 
WHERE Timestamp > CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112)

SELECT * 
FROM DatesView 
WHERE Timestamp > '20120423'
```

The top one looks through all tables where the bottom one correctly only searches the necessary tables.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try selecting `'''' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) +''''` to see what it actually represents?

Comment: Not related to your question, but the first sentence of your post suggests that your database design might be sub-optimal.

Comment: So disregarding the database design, should the two queries in my edit be treated the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting thrown off by the quote marks, just remove them they are unnecessary.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) 

IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112)  = '20120423' 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'VALUES ARE THE SAME'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'VALUES ARE NOT THE SAME'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the first two `'`. Try this.
You are comparing `'20120423'=20120423`

```
SELECT '' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) +'' 

IF '' +CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) +''  = '20120423' 
BEGIN
    PRINT 'VALUES ARE THE SAME'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   PRINT 'VALUES ARE NOT THE SAME'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding apostrophes to the string, so your comparison is *literally* (replacing the string delimiters with brackets):

```
if ['20120423']  = [20120423]
```

I think you want:

```
IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112) = '20120423'
```

and/or

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112)
```

Comment: To my surprise, this also works IF CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), DateAdd(YY,-2,GETDATE()), 112)  = 20120423 ie without the apostrophes. I suppose it is a varchar that just happens to look like a number.

Comment: @JohnBarça That works because SQL will _implicitly_ convert the string to a number in order to compare it to a number.

Comment: So after my edit, those two queries "should" be treated the same correct?